# how to find tuples in haskell with same numbers

Tags: haskell

How would you filter tuples in Haskell that have doubles within them such as (1,1) and (2,2) but not to remove them just to find them?

```
So far all i have is the start line 
FilterDoubles.
```

Comment: All you have is… what? The function's name? Also, what would you filter? A list of tuples?

Comment: what do you want to filter - lists? Foldables? - or do you want a function that can deal with tuples of different *sizes*?

Comment: yeh the functions name and it would be filtering a list of tuples.

Comment: what about example input/output. show at least as much effort as you would expect someone writing an answer for your question!

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
> let xs = [(1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 3)]
```

to `filter` (select only)

```
> filter (uncurry (==)) xs
[(3,3)]
```

to mark

```
> [(a == b, t) | t@(a, b) <- xs]
[(False,(1,2)),(True,(3,3)),(False,(4,3))]
```

play with and understand this expressions yourself!

Comment: Can you comment your -1 please?

Comment: it's not form me - but don't worry to much - probably someone disagreed with you answering a slightly bad question (it was probably no Haskeller here - but there are SO sheriffs that patrol every negative question and downvote/flat, etc. what they see as not helping encourage good questions and answer)

Comment: IMO your answer is fine and correct as far as we can know from the question and the only clarifying comment